# Getting Xdebug to work with Dev Desktop

Tags: debugging, acquia-dev-desktop

I'm trying to get xdebug to work with Dev Desktop.

I am following the instructions in this guide:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1846954

and I still get the message, "waiting to connect" well after it should have already connected and the site is showing in my browser.

My zend_extension also starts out as:

```
zend_extension="C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\php5_5\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
```

And I'm not sure which version to get off of here:

http://xdebug.org/download.php

I'm somewhat lost - I have no problems getting xdebug to work on OSX or Linux, but I seem to be having real trouble getting it to work on Windows

Comment: Have you checked `phpinfo()` to make sure the extension is loaded in your environment?

Comment: When searching for xdebug in my phpinfo(), it does not appear. This is despite my php.ini having the following line: 
zend_extension="C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\php5_5\ext\php_xdebug.dll"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to address your concern about which version to download, if the instructions state **Program Files (x86)** then you want the **32-bit** version of the dll. I'm not sure VC++ 9 or VC++11 should matter. As far as thread safe, you should check `phpinfo()` in your DevDesktop environment to make sure it's thread safe or not.

The XDebug site has a [nifty wizard form](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php) where you can copy/paste your `phpinfo()` into it and it will point you to the version you need.

Comment: Yep, got the correct version, tested while disabling Windows firewall, and everything worked.